# How to hide all divs in jquery of particular div?

Tags: jquery, html

I have HTML like below

```
<div  id="L0" >
    <div id="P0">
      //code
    </div>
    <div id="P1">
         //code
    </div>
    <div id="p2">
           //code
    </div>
</div>
<div  id="L1" >
    <div id="P0">
      //code
    </div>
    <div id="P1">
         //code
    </div>
    <div id="p2">
           //code
    </div>
</div>
```

So I want to hide all inner P divs of particular L. I have tried below code but it is not working.

```
$('#L0 div[id^=P]').hide();
```

Comment: Try `$('div[id^="L"] div[id^="P"]').hide();`

Comment: It works for me http://jsfiddle.net/aq5o1f7k/ unless i didn't understand the question

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#L0 div[id^=P], #L0 div[id^=p]').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Last `div` id `p` is small char and in selector used CAPITAL `P` char

```
<div id="p2">
```

change

```
<div id="P2">
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Two of them are not hiding because they are small letter p

```js
$('div[id^="P"]').hide();
$('div[id^="p"]').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  id="L0" >
    <div id="P0">
      //code
    </div>
    <div id="P1">
         //code
    </div>
    <div id="p2">
           //code
    </div>
</div>
<div  id="L1" >
    <div id="P0">
      //code
    </div>
    <div id="P1">
         //code
    </div>
    <div id="p2">
           //code
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Girish How about now it was because two of them started with small letter p

Answer (score 0):

just hide your L0 div and all inner P will hide automatically for particular Div
try following code

```
$('#L0').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your top level **DIV**'s for example:

```
<div id="L0" class="top-div">
    <div id="P0">1</div>
    <div id="P1">2</div>
    <div id="p2">3</div>
</div>
<div id="L1" class="top-div">
    <div id="P0">4</div>
    <div id="P1">5</div>
    <div id="p2">6</div>
</div>
```

Now you can easily select all **DIV's** with the class **top-div** and hide their children, In this case the inner divs:

```
$('div.top-div').children().hide();
```

If you want to hide the inner divs of only one outer (L) div use the code below:

```
$('div#L0').children().hide();// for your first div L0
$('div#L1').children().hide();// for your second div L1
```